# Mouse pad error after new Linux kernel install

Tags: kernel, hardware-compatibility

Yesterday I upgraded my debian laptop with the backports repository. Amongst the packages it installed, a new kernel was added (3.2.0). When booting on this kernel, the right-click on my mouse pad (is it called that way?) doesn't work. I tried booting on my old kernel (2.6.39) and it works like a charm.

I have a bunch of live CDs for various distros lying around on my desk, so I tried launching live sessions. It confirmed my idea that it is a kernel issue. My hardware doesn't work well with recent kernels.

My question is not how to solve my particular problem (I'm not even giving details about my hardware). What's the way to go when facing such a problem? Can anyone point me to good documentation?